# MySQL Group By query produces indeterminate results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem ...
I have one request, but each time I'm refresh the request, the result changes.
Here is my request

```
  SELECT `t`.*, COUNT('ID') AS `tr` FROM (
  SELECT * FROM HISTORY WHERE USER_ID = 1 AND BIEN_ID IS NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY CREATED_AT DESC) AS `t` WHERE (`USER_ID` = 1) 
  GROUP BY `t`.`BIEN_ID` ORDER BY `t`.`CREATED_AT` DESC
```

I actually want to group by `BIEN_ID` with the most recent `CREATED_AT`field
Is someone can help me?

For example, first time I got this:

```
ID   |USER_ID| BIEN_ID | CREATED_AT  
205  |   1   |     36  | 2015-06-10 17:00:36  
203  |   1   |     48  | 2015-06-10 17:00:2
```

And after I got this:

```
ID  | USER_ID| BIEN_ID | CREATED_AT  
202 | 1      | 7       | 2015-06-10 16:31:48  
196 | 1      | 48      | 2015-06-10 16:23:4
```

---

Here is my HISTORY DB:

```
ID  | USER_ID| BIEN_ID | CREATED_AT  
202 | 1      | 7       | 2015-06-10 16:31:48  
199 | 1      | 48      | 2015-06-10 16:23:40   
196 | 1      | 48      | 2015-06-09 16:23:31  
140 | 1      | 7       | 2015-06-09 10:01:20   
134 | 1      | 30      | 2015-06-04 09:10:11
100 | 1      | 48      | 2015-06-01 11:32:40
```

And here is what I expect (I want to GROUP BY `ID`, COUNT the same `BIEN_ID`, and get the most recent CREATED_AT)

```
ID  | USER_ID| BIEN_ID | COUNT | CREATED_AT  
202 | 1      | 7       | 2     | 2015-06-10 16:31:48  
199 | 1      | 48      | 3     | 2015-06-10 16:23:40   
134 | 1      | 30      | 1     | 2015-06-04 09:10:11
```

Comment: Please give an example of how the results are changing.

Comment: `140 | 1      | 30      | 1     | 2015-06-04 09:10:11` it sould be `134 | 1      | 30      | 1     | 2015-06-04 09:10:11` ? N where user_id always be 1 ?

Comment: @NagendraNigade Yes, my bad, you're right, it's 134

Comment: `select * from (select max(ID),BIEN_ID , count(*) as TOTAL,max(CREATED_AT) as NEW_DATE from temp1 group by BIEN_ID) temp1 order by NEW_DATE desc;` this will work fine. Whether you also want `USER_ID` as i can see it's always 1. Check : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3e43/12

Comment: instead of `max(ID` only use `ID`

Comment: Wait...if i changed `196 | 1      | 48      | 2015-06-09 16:23:31` to `196 | 1      | 48      | 2016-06-09 16:23:31` my query giving wrong o/p. Ideally it should give `196` but its still giving `199` :(

Comment: @AlbertBin : Check new query . this will work fine with any case.

Answer (score 5):

You are using an extension to MySQL `GROUP BY` that is *explicitly* [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) to return indeterminate results. Hence, you should not be surprised that you are getting, well, indeterminate results.

The problem is that you are doing `select *` in a `group by` query. The `group by` column is `t.bien_id` -- I am guessing from the context that this is not a unique id on each row. (If so, the count would always be 1 and the query would work consistently from run-to-run.)

The specific documentation is:

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to
> nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means
> that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
> to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
> grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
> nonaggregated column not named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each
> group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
> unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

Comment: You're right about this being too long for a comment, but it does explain the problem pretty well. If the OP adjusts their query to only select the columns that are consistent in each group, then it may work, correct? Certainly there may be other factors, but it's kind of hard for me to tell.

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . In theory.  Actually, the OP should simply ask another question with sample data and desired results.  He should focus on what his wants to accomplish rather than asking why an incorrect query produces indeterminate results.  There is a solution to the problem, and it is nothing like the query in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you. I edited my question, with waht I really want. I still not understand how to do it in one query ...

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id,a.user_id,a.bien_id,a.created_at,b.TOTAL_OCCURANCES from (select *
 from temp1 where created_at in (select MAX(created_at) from temp1 group by
 BIEN_ID))a , (select count(*) as TOTAL_OCCURANCES,BIEN_ID from temp1 group by
 BIEN_ID) b where a.BIEN_ID=b.BIEN_ID order by CREATED_AT desc;
```

This will perfectly work as you expected.

Fiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3e43/22/3